# Can't get dot in query string

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the url i request :

```
localhost/register... // with dotes at the end
```

when trying to get URI using `$_GET`:

```
echo $_GET['uri'];
```

It returns `register`.

I have only 2 file :
.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  home.php?uri=$1    [L,NC,QSA]
```

and home.php :

```
<?php
echo $_GET['uri'];
?>
```

How can i get exact query string ?

Edit :
it works when url is like this :

```
localhost/home.php?uri=register.. // returns register..
```

but not works when url is like this :

```
localhost/register... // returns register
```

Comment: Your example works for me.  Debian: Google Chrome  Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) and Mozilla Firefox 46.0a1  Apache/2.2.22, PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2. What's your environment?

Comment: Perhaps your web browser is trying to do some folder traversal and stripping the dots.  Try another browser.

Comment: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.6.17 
Firefox 44
Also tried with chrome

Comment: It also doesn't show multiple slashes at the end of `URL`

Comment: Trailing slashes are combined into one for the rewritten parameter for me too.  What does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` show?  (Determine if it's the browser or server peeling them off.)

Comment: `/register...`
thats correct

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: no only htaccess and a file that contains only `echo $_GET['uri'];`
no other files and folder. i tested with xampp and easyPHP. i got same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your rule with this rule where we are capturing value from `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xampp/external/projects/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xampp/external/projects/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ page.php?uri=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please tell me how redirect non www URLs to www  considering these conditions ?